# How do i prevent SDK Version Issue when Using nativescript sidekick to build my ios app

Tags: ios, nativescript, sidekick

When i build my app using Nativescript Sidekick, i get a warning , which is confirmed by mail from apple, telling me that i need to deliver my app using the latest SDK version.

> ITMS-90725: SDK Version Issue - This app was built with the iOS 12.4
>   SDK. Starting April 2020, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must
>   be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later, included in Xcode 11 or later.

But i assume this is the SideKick's xcode, as i am building my IPA through sidekick. Do i need to do anything or will sidekick be updating before April2020 ????

Comment: Please attach your `package.json`.

Comment: How do i attach a file to the Iassue ?

Comment: You can copy paste it's contents.

Comment: OK thanks Manoj, and for all your help in previous questions too, i could not find how i could thank you, but using a comment on your reaction seems to do the trick. thanks again. oh i solved THIS problem by updating as FrontEnder sugested.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your project with nativescript 6.5.0 and install xcode11 from 
https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

1.Update nativescript using this command:-

```
npm install -g nativescript
```

2.If your code is not migrate with nativescript 6 then use this command:-

```
tns migrate
```

3.After update your project node_modules and tns_core_modules:-

```
tns update
```

4.Add platform

```
tns platform add android
```

Comment: I am not using xcode , i develop on Windows and use Sidekick to create the IPA then upload on an apple through transporter... Do i have to install xcode ii on the apple only if i only use transporter ?